# R - how to shift a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, r

I am working with a multi-dimensional array:

```
> dim(Sales)
[1] 35 71  5
```

which I use to perform operations like comparing sales year over year:

```
Sales_Increase_Y2_to_Y1 = Sales[,,2]-Sales[,,1]
```

Now I would like to be able to shift one dimension to calculate Sales increase across all years in one line:

**Sales-Sales[,,*how to call previous year here?*]**

---

Example to build sample multi-dim array:

```
x = structure(list(Store = c(35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L), Dept = c(71L, 
71L, 71L, 71L, 71L), Year = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Sales = c(10908.04, 
12279.99, 11061.82, 12288.1, 9950.55)), .Names = c("Store", "Dept", 
"Year", "Sales"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")        

> x
  Store Dept Year    Sales
1    35   71    1 10908.04
2    35   71    2 12279.99
3    35   71    3 11061.82
4    35   71    4 12288.10
5    35   71    5  9950.55

Sales <- array(NA, c(max(x$Store), max(x$Dept), max(x$Year)))

for (i in 1:nrow(x)) 
    Sales[x[i,"Store"], x[i,"Dept"], x[i,"Year"]] <- x[i, "Sales"]

Sales[35,71,1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Bonus tip

When assigning or extracting parts of an array (or matrix), you can either use a number of vectors like you do in your example, or a matrix of array coordinates

```
Sales[as.matrix(x[1:3])] <- x$Sales
```

#### The actual problem

You can then calculate the difference between the years with `apply`. Since we want to work over dimension 3 (the years), but keep the other dimensions 1 and 2 intact we set `MARGIN=1:2` (the second argument)

```
Sales.diff <- apply(Sales, 1:2, diff)
```

However, notice that the dimensions have been shifted now, putting the differences first

```
> dim(Sales.diff)
[1]  4 35 71
```

but you can get the order back with `aperm`

```
> Sales.diff <- aperm(sd, c(2,3,1))
> dim(Sales.diff)
[1]  35 71 4
```

#### Alternative solution

This will keep the order of the dimensions too.

```
Sales[,,-1] - Sales[,,-dim(Sales)[3]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the bonus tip! Excellent... except I don't understand where is the part where you say you want the difference across years, and not another variable (Store for example).

Comment: Also I still would like to know how to access the previous (or the next) year directly (without having to through the diff) if there is any possible way...

Comment: I mean that if you want to know the difference in Sales between years, which is dimension 3, you supply the other dimension *i.e.* 1:2 to `apply`. You can off course calculate the difference between store `y` and store `y-1` by `apply(..., 2:3, ...)` too if you want to (although it might not be meaningful).

Comment: You could do `Sales[,,-1] - Sales[,,-dim(Sales)[3]]`. That would preseve the dimension too.